# No More Jockeys - CodeGolf Version

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, game

This challenge is inspired by the game [No More Jockeys](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS8aP7SiA_eTfvT_Gruxzsw).

The input is a list of tuples of natural numbers (potentially including 0), in some appropriate input format. Starting with player 0 and alternating with player 1, each player chooses some number which is contained within at least one remaining tuple, and all tuples containing that number will be removed from the list. The first player who has no possible moves loses.

Your challenge is to implement a function to calculate the minimax value of a given input. Return a truthy value if it is player 1 to win given optimal play by both players, and a falsy value if it is player 0 to win. The converse is also acceptable.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so fewest bytes wins.

### Test Cases

```
((), (0, 1, 3), (1,)) -> 0
() -> 1
((0,), (1, 3), (2,)) -> 0
((), (0, 1), (0, 1, 2), (0, 2), (1,)) -> 1
((0,), (0, 1, 3), (0, 3), (2,)) -> 0
((), (0, 1), (0, 2, 3), (1,), (2,), (3,)) -> 1
((0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3,)) -> 0
((0, 2), (1,), (1, 3), (3,), (4,)) -> 1
((0, 2, 3), (0, 3), (1,), (2,), (2, 3)) -> 0
```

Comment: May we take the inner tuples as `set` objects?

Comment: @xnor OK, that's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
iÐḟⱮẎß€0e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/z8ISHO@Y/2rju4a6@w/MfNa0xSP1/uB1IR/7/r6GhqaOgYaCjYKijYAxiGupoauoABTWAghA@RNwILA5XjdBlBGUaIXRDtSKZaoDXFCOE3RA1QNIYZhJEFcwimFKEtBFCpyFCEkiaIJSguQLZHrCcJgA)

My first attempt repeatedly segfaulted, but now that I have a very close translation of hyper-neutrino's Python solution it seems to work fine.

I would be remiss to let this get accepted without an explanation!

```
   Ɱ         For each element of
    Ẏ        the input flattened a level,
 Ðḟ          yield the input without elements which
i            contain the element in question.
     ß€      Recur on each result.
       0e    Is one of those results 0?
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 62 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:0in(f([x for x in a if{r}-{*x}])for r in sum(a,()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY8/T8MwEMXn5lOcMt2Bi/KHKahsDKyoG2JwqKNaSlLLcSCo6mcPdkywy8Ji@95797uz@jLHU1/Oc7NreVcfOPAqkz02@DpBc9IwgeyBg2zO@rI930yXN3KydvIwdsgZEtFsYAd58nmUrYC9HkWVbDiD2qodVyg@eMtshxoN0t2gWmkwhe0jpETJRmnZ23ovBpMyMPQABm4dbnWeXWNlPR7ST5MS70YcnFwH@UUMY7tkG@QBTjMiMcCMQc6gdM@cEbkVsgSXO0/Q2t7xiSIkfpsDpPh5FjEsQKJJ2f@8Iizlg/Ysr5g@us5d82WEjHaJPlEu1f01q/izWTx28Tz0Gw)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 61 bytes

```python
f=lambda a:0in(f(filter({y}.__sub__,a))for x in a for y in x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY8xb4MwEIXn8itOTGfVjcB0Ikq3Dl2r7Mg0RrHkEAuOBlT1t1MbCjhdupjj3vP3nu1A52stxrE6GHkpTxJknugaK6y0IdXg1/C9K4q2K4uCS8aqawM96Bok@HHwY89GggOk0e2sjYJj06k8epAcSre9SIvqUxoOjbwVurYdIdu11mjCGJ5eIGbMmZ2TOmsUtoqwZ7DlONU2uiaIj6qlmAPtgeDR5y3Cm6fmTpLr6rW36oPUyW/Ldfuu2s5MzgpX8IjIOGDCIeWQ@THljPlqSYTTN43QybMyO8TmWC9vEPE7ihC2QYKk5H@e2ErNRndmd8zZuuQu/ixABl2CR2TT3/M9S/xpFsZO2gz9AQ)

-5 bytes thanks to Unrelated String
-6 bytes thanks to dingledooper
-1 byte if we use Python 2 thanks to dingledooper
-2 bytes thanks to xnor

Outputs `True` for player 0 winning and `False` or `()` for player 1 winning (`()` is an empty tuple in Python, which is a falsey value in the language)

Comment: [-5](https://tio.run/##hY89T8MwEIbn5lecMt2Bi/LRKajdGFhRN8TgEFuN5KRW4kBQ1d8e7IRgl4XBX@/73nNn/WVO5zafJrlXvCkrDrywq60gPXClUOLrCPLcwQh1Cxxqeemu28vdeH0jJ3dO7ocGOUMimgzsIY0@T7UScOwGUUQbzqC0asM1ig@umK3Qg0F66LWqDcawPUBMFG10V7f2fRS9iRkYegQD9w63Os@usLAe9@mnUYt3Iyonl15@Ef2g5qxE7uE0IRIDTBikDHJ3TRmRGyGJcD7TCK29OEsi84nfYg/Jfq5ZCPOQoFPyPy/zQy1Bu@c3zCW69l3zeYAMZgk@kc@v3S0r@zNZ2Hb2Fug3)

Comment: ([Taking the inner tuples as sets on top of that seems to cost one more byte than it saves, since sets can't be added, but I might be missing something.](https://tio.run/##hY@9boMwFIXn8hRXTPe2TsRPJ6pk69C1ylZ1MMUolhxjgUmoqj47taEEp0sHjH3O53Ouzac9Njofx3qn@KmsOPDCfbqCdM@VwhrfBqibFgaQGjjI@qv93gzv5LXWa52w217LRuM9Jxot7CCNLkepBBzaXhTRHWdQOvXEDYozV8zdMr1F2nZGSYsxbPYQEznQUbY3SqALxYGCYueaVmpHH0RnYwaWnsDCgy9bnBcfWzgvoJ8HIz6sqLxcrvKr6Ho1sTVyuuo0IhIDTBikDHK/TRmRHzCJcPqnETp7dmYiW4nr5TUk@91mYdgaEjQl/@dl61Az6Nb8JnNGl96Fz4PIYJbgEfl0erzNyv5MFtZO3hz6Aw))

Comment: It seems to [pass](https://tio.run/##hY8/T8MwEMXn5lOcMt2Bi/KnU1C7MbCibojhQh01kpNaiQNBVT97sBOKXRYW2/feu9@d9Zc5ntp8mqqt4qY8MHCR7lgprPB1hOrUwQh1Cwx1de4u6/PdeHkjJ3dO7ocGWSARTQa2kEafx1pJ2HeDLKIVCyit2rBG@cFK2A49GKSHXqvaYAzrHcRE0Up3dWvrvexNLMDQIxi4d7ir8@waC@uxTz@NWr4beXBy6eUX2Q9qzlbIHk4TIgnAREAqIHfPVBC5FZII5zuN0NqLsyQyn/ht9pDs55mFMA8JJiX/8zK/1BK0Z37DXKLXudd8HiCDXYJP5HO1uWVlfzYLx87eAv0G) all the test cases even after removing the `a and...` condition, saving 6 bytes. It also correctly returns `False` for that empty tuple.

Comment: @dingledooper oh right, that makes sense for how `all` works. thanks

Comment: There's also a [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##hY8xb4MwEIXn8itOTGfVjcB0okq2Dl2r7Mg0RrHkEAuOBlT1t1MbCjhdupjj3vP3nu1A52stxrHaG3kpTxJknh6kMVhhpQ2pBr@G711RtF1ZFFwyVl0b6EHXIMGPgx97NhLsIY1uZ20UHJtO5dGD5FC67UVaVJ/ScGjkrdC17QjZrrVGE8bwdICYMWd2TuqsUdgqwp7BluNU2@iaID6qlmIO9AIEjz5vEd48NXeSXFevvVUfpE5@W67bd9V2ZnJWuIJHRMYBEw4ph8yPKWfMV0sinL5phE6eldkhNsd6eYOI31GEsA0SJCX/88RWaja6M7tjztYld/FnATLoEjwim/6e71niT7MwdtJm6A8) save in Python 2, but that's all I can find now.

Comment: It looks like `1-all(...)` can be `0in[...]`.

Comment: @xnor oh right - cuz 0 is the same thing as false, lol. thanks!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES10), 54 bytes

Returns a Boolean value.

```javascript
f=a=>!a.flat().some(v=>f(a.filter(b=>!b.includes(v))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZFNDoMgEIX3nmK6w8QiancN7noKwwIVWxsqjVqvbxH/o7WzmEyYx@Mb5skbXiVl/q7PhUpF22aU0/DEcSZ5jWxcqZdADQ0zpI9yWYsSxbof47xI5CcVFWpsHe01sgCiiDkQEQc8B4Ku9BhsQzdcF0ivh//R6z2jJ8Z1cPfZgZ6seGYufyj9iW/jvxiA7Dx14O9Pc5s7OgVs7T9oR5DxQvDDfwZdzG3She3@z8xANiymo/XQ@zMLZ6q88eSBONAQElVUSgos1R3pdXdb/QI)

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
f a=any(not.f.(`filter`a).notElem)$a>>=id
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY4xD4IwFIT/ysU4tBEJVCcT2BxMNA6OtdEmQiBCJVAj/nosFalxcODl9e67e2SyuSZF0XUpZCTVk6ib9lOfnNO80El9ltQ3yrpISjqVcRzll66UuUIEUifyslVYrbDZg3O@UVoIQWEolLLanUCO7TxGddcHXRtyiia7PdBiNsMExpn0m9VIipbSzrQIDzzwEHpY9Gso@tl/PLDvQWdWH2mXYsPKXPqd/CoN/paw8bRFzFgMNQPzufIBnc3GXDh6Ziwd8PMH7oZ1hHgB)

*Was* the same length as using nested list comprehensions, until I realized `notElem` exists, and is much shorter than `(not.).elem`. Still feels very golfable...

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 37 bytes

```
(0=1#.]$:@#~1-~.@;e.&>/])`1:@.(''-:;)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY7BCgIhEIbv@xRDG6mQ5mgnxRCCTp26LxSxy9KlN9hXt9EN0kug/@jM//36ShvFJggOGOxBg6MtFZxv10viOmCvhq2L/YJyUdGPanc6DOKOLirOmHReJNF143N@ExdgAsY814Bghce1j6X/cLVL@2zxYGoLoTTGImByIcEWK9Gkf1iTh3Qi2DZwbpbg4rA1vj71/RStYwsWQP9y6d6lDw)

Inspired by Arnauld's answer.